Why is val_accuracy not changing or changing between two values?
I'm making CNN+LSTM model for video classification, drowsiness classification to be exact. Im using SUSTDDD, where i divided 19 people into training:val:test datasets in proportions 13:3:3 (70:15:15). Im using pretrained model VGG16 with added LSTM layer. Here's my code:
image_height = 224
image_width = 224
batch_size = 6
n_of_frames = 50
NUM_OF_CLASSES = 2
NUM_OF_CHANNELS = 3

input_shape = (n_of_frames, image_height, image_width, NUM_OF_CHANNELS)

video = Input(shape=input_shape)
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(image_height, image_width, NUM_OF_CHANNELS),
                 weights="imagenet",
                 include_top=False)
cnn_base.trainable = False

cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)
cnn = Model(cnn_base.input, cnn_out)
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)

encoded_sequence1 = LSTM(1024)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer1 = Dense(512, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence1)
hidden_layer2 = Dropout(0.3)(hidden_layer1)
outputs = Dense(NUM_OF_CLASSES, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer2)

model = Model(video, outputs)


optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 50, 224, 224, 3   0         
                             )]                                  
                                                                 
 time_distributed (TimeDist  (None, 50, 512)           14714688  
 ributed)                                                        
                                                                 
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 1024)              6295552   
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 512)               524800    
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 512)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 1026      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 21536066 (82.15 MB)
Trainable params: 6821378 (26.02 MB)
Non-trainable params: 14714688 (56.13 MB)

The problem is model doesn't seem to train properly. Training accuracy fluctuates and doesn't wanna go up. Validation accuracy is stuck on one/two values. Network predicts only one class all the time.

[Curves](https://i.sstatic.net/6HHG5ysB.png)
[Confusion matrix](https://i.sstatic.net/fzXMbUb6.png)


Here's my custom data generator:
class CustomSequenceGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, directory, batch_size, n_of_frames, target_size, shuffle=True):
        self.directory = directory
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_of_frames = n_of_frames
        self.target_size = target_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.skip_step = 1
        self.sequences = self.load_filepaths()
        np.random.shuffle(self.sequences)
        if self.directory =='/workspace/SUSTDDD/val' or self.directory =='/workspace/SUSTDDD/test':
            self.sequences = self.balance_dataset(self.sequences, 161)
        if self.directory =='/workspace/SUSTDDD/train':
            self.sequences = self.balance_dataset(self.sequences, 2000)
        print(self.list_sequences(self.sequences))
        
    def load_filepaths(self): 
        filepaths = []
        count = 0
        total_jpg_files = 0
       
        for clas in os.listdir(self.directory):
            for vid in os.listdir(os.path.join(self.directory, clas)):
                single_sequence = []
                if vid.endswith(".zip"):
                    continue
                sub_vids = os.listdir(os.path.join(self.directory, clas, vid))
                for sub_vid in sub_vids:
                    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(self.directory, clas, vid, sub_vid))
                    files.sort()
    
                    for idx, file in enumerate(files):
                        if file.lower().endswith('.png') or file.lower().endswith('.jpg') or file.lower().endswith('.jpeg'):
                            if idx % self.skip_step == 0:
                                filepath = os.path.join(self.directory, clas, vid, sub_vid, file)
                                single_sequence.append(filepath)
                                if len(single_sequence) == self.n_of_frames:
                                    filepaths.append(single_sequence)
                                    single_sequence = []
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(filepaths)
        return filepaths

    def list_sequences(self, filepaths):
        classes = {"D": 0, "ND": 0}
        
        for idx, filepath in enumerate(filepaths):
            for k, v in classes.items():
                if k == filepath[0].split('/')[4]:
                    classes[k] += 1
        return classes

    def balance_dataset(self, filepaths, max_cap):
        classes = {"D": 0, "ND": 0}
        to_remove = []
        for idx, filepath in enumerate(filepaths):
            for k, v in classes.items():
                if k == filepath[0].split('/')[4]:
                    classes[k] += 1
                    if v >= max_cap:
                        to_remove.append(filepath)
        for j in to_remove:
            filepaths.remove(j)
        return filepaths
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sequences) // self.batch_size
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_sequences = self.sequences[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_images = []
        batch_labels = []
        
        for j, sequence in enumerate(batch_sequences):
            batch_single_sequence = []
            current_class = -1

            for image_path in sequence:
                tf_image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
                decoded_image = tf.image.decode_image(tf_image, dtype=tf.float32)
                image_resized = tf.image.resize(decoded_image, self.target_size)
                image_batch = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(image_resized)
                batch_single_sequence.append(image_batch)
                
                current_class = image_path.split('/')[4]
                if current_class == "D":
                    current_class = 1
                elif current_class == "ND":
                    current_class = 0

            batch_images.append(batch_single_sequence)
            batch_labels.append(current_class)
        
        batch_images = np.array(batch_images)
        batch_labels = np.array(batch_labels)
       
        batch_labels = to_categorical(batch_labels, num_classes=NUM_OF_CLASSES)
        #print(np.shape(batch_images), np.shape(batch_labels))
        return batch_images, batch_labels

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.sequences)

So far I've tried:

Changing model complexity to 3 Conv Layers and 1 LSTM Layer
Using different pretrained models (VGG16, VGG19, ResNet50, InceptionV3) with expected normalized frames sizes to each of them (i. e. 224 x 224 for VGG16, 299 x 299 for InceptionV3)
Changing learning rate from 0.01 to 1e-6
Using different optimizers (Adam, SGD, RMSprop)
Using different dataset (RLDD - a bit different approach but outcome is the same)
Adding dropout or reccurent dropout
Using binary cross entropy with sigmoid activation function
Using tensorflow built in normalization tools, i. e.

decoded_image = tf.image.decode_image(tf_image, dtype=tf.float32)
image_resized = tf.image.resize(decoded_image, self.target_size)
image = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(image_resized)


Balancing training, testing and validating dataset

I'm out of ideas.

Training a CNN+LSTM model for video classification, especially for tasks like drowsiness detection, can indeed be challenging, but there are several strategies and adjustments you can consider to improve your model's performanceData Generator,
Your custom data generator looks generally well-implemented, ensuring that frames are read correctly and resized appropriately for the VGG16 model.Ensure that your data is properly shuffled, especially if there are patterns in your data that could bias training.
